# Angular 2 ng2-scroll-to not working

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to use [ng2-scroll-to](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-scroll-to) in my app, but it doesn't seem to be working and I can't figure out what is wrong.

I've imported it in my app.module.ts

```
import { ScrollToModule } from 'ng2-scroll-to';
```

and imported it in @NgModule

```
ScrollToModule.forRoot()
```

then in my app.component.html

```
<a scrollTo href="#scrolltome">Scroll to Div</a>

//more content in here 

<div id="#scrolltome">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```

Not sure why it wouldn't be working and I'm not getting any errors in the console. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div id="scrolltome">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```

Little correction in your code

Comment: Genius why didn't i see that